# Issues with SQL - SELECT between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, select

I got this old system that I have to do maintenance in the place I work and they asked me to add a Date Filter on the system, but the date field is not only a field, the previous developer has split it in *three*, just like that "**year_id**", "**month_id**", "**day_id**"

And now I have to do a SELECT between the two dates (between the **month** and **year** to be more specific) and I tried just like that:

```
select 
    * from `table` 
where 
    ( 
        (`year_id` >= 2018 and `month_id` >= 10) 
    or 
        (`year_id` <= 2019 and `month_id` <= 3) 
    )
```

When I saw the results I realized that the query is also returning the results from **Jan, Feb and Mar of 2018** and it is not supposed to do that.
How can I apply those filters?

Comment: did you try on this format? : "SELECT * FROM TABLE where startdate <= '$startdate' and enddate >= '$enddate'"

Comment: Even though there can be workarounds to this problem, I recommend you to add a new column to the table containing a date field with implode values of the 3 columns. That'll help you to filter easily

Comment: Be more specific - if you don't want years prior to 2019 for the second clause, don't use `<=`.

Comment: If you look closely this criteria suggests that ANY `year < 2019` with `month 1,2,3` is a candidate for selection, so every year less than 2019.

    `(`year_id` <= 2019 and `month_id` <= 3)`

Likewise this criteria gets EVERY year > 2018 as well if the months are 10,11,12

    `(`year_id` >= 2018 and `month_id` >= 10)`

Comment: Why not simply fix your model?

Comment: Strawberry, this program is running for a few years, no documentation... I do not want to break something on it and do a lot of work only to add a filter... also we are currently working on a new version, but we still got to do some support on this legacy version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to write a query that implements a date range filtering based on input parameters and on the existing columns. For example if you want records between October 2018 and March 2019 (inclusive), you could do:

```
(year_id = 2018 and month_id >= 10)
or (year_id = 2019 and month_id <= 3)
```

However the logic need to be adapted depending on the date range. For example if you want records between October 2017 and March 2019, then you need:

```
(year_id = 2017 and month_id >= 10)
or year_id = 2018
or (year_id = 2019 and month_id <= 3)
```

You can see that this does not scale well. For the sake of simplicity, I would suggest using `str_to_date()` to convert your strings to date, so you can do proper date comparison:

```
str_to_date(concat (year_id, '-', month_id), '%Y-%m') between '2017-10-01' and '2019-03-01'
```

You could add a computed column to your table that prepares the date value for you:

```
alter table mytable add 
    mydate date as (str_to_date(concat (year_id, '-', month_id), '%Y-%m'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The ideal thing you should do is add a new column

```
select 
    *,STR_TO_DATE(Concat(year_id,month_id),'%Y%m') as 'YearMonth' from `table`;
```

This would create a new column `YearMonth` and then you can use your filters

```
select * from (
select 
        *,STR_TO_DATE(Concat(year_id,month_id),'%Y%m') as 'YearMonth' from `table`
) z where (YearMonth between '201810' and '201903')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone that answered && added comments, I just fixed the problem.

The solution posted by GMB worked well, you just saved me <3

I did like u suggested:

```
$data_inicial = Controller::toDate($data_inicial, 'm/Y', 'Y-m') . '-01';
$data_final = Controller::toDate($data_final, 'm/Y', 'Y-m') . '-01';
$query->whereBetween(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(sicc_ano_id, '-', sicc_mes_id), '%Y-%m')"), [$data_inicial, $data_final]);
```